# All possible combinations of arrays where each element of the array has 4 possible numbers, python

Tags: python

```
list=[]
angles=np.array([0,30,45,60])
for i in angles:
    for j in angles:
        for k in angles:
            for m in angles:
                for n in angles:
                    list.append(np.array([i,j,k,m,n]))
```

Basically, I want the above code but faster. This is too slow

Comment: What do you need to _do_ with the combinations? Once the code you have in your question completes, `list` would be thrown away.

Comment: I think there's a method called `permutation` in the `itertools` library

Comment: This is an simplification of my problem. The original problem has actually 17 "if" statements and the angles array is the same. I need to compare all the arrays in order to find the most optimum solution in my problem (its about composite laminates)

Comment: What -precisely- is slow? Is it just the generation time up-front? If so, move all your logic to build comparisons into an iterator that spits out the next combo on demand. That will amortize your time across your other calculations (and if you're doing anything cpu-intensive, I imagine those will swamp this).

Comment: I tried all the itertools library but nothing does what I want, except I use them the wrong way

Comment: The total number of combinations I want to check is 85000. Using if statements will take around 17 hours to solve it. Thanks, I will check it

Comment: Also never name a variable like a builtin name like `list` of you won't be able to use the method `list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you looking for is permutation with repetition. 
You can do it like this.

```
import intertools
angles=np.array([0,30,45,60])
all_combinations = [p for p in itertools.product(angles, repeat=4)]
```

Answer (score 2):

`itertools.product` (Cartesian product) should do the trick:

```py
import itertools

angles=[0,30,45,60]
res=list(itertools.product(*(angles for i in range(5))))

print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i tried it but it keeps saying 'list' object is not callable. I dont know why, I am a beginner in programming, probably I have some stupid mistake somehwere

Comment: Thanks a lot, i tried it but it keeps saying 'list' object is not callable. I dont know why, I am a beginner in programming, probably I have some stupid mistake somehwere

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `itertools.product` and its `reapeat` param:

```
angles = [0, 30, 45, 60]
all_perm = list(product(angles, repeat=5))
print(all_perm) # {(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ..., (60, 60, 60, 60, 60)] len=1024
```

Comment: @EvgeniosSastix thanks, I'm force to tell you to think about the answer you accept, seems the one you accepted is (not exactly giving the good result as he used 4 and not 5) also for performance : list comprehension is not a good as just list() ;)

Comment: Thanks, I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `product` from `itertools` as mentioned in the previous answer. However, you can use the `repeat` to specify the number of repetitions to compute the product of the list with itself

```
from itertools import product 
l = [i for i in product([0,30,45,60], repeat = 5)] 
print(l)
```